# What exactly does Compass / Blurprint's +clearfix do?

Tags: css, blueprint-css, compass-sass

Ususally, I use a `div` to clear the floats

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

In Compass / Blueprint, there is a

```
+clearfix
```

What exactly does it do?  Does it clear the current floating element, instead of clearing the floats up above?  Does that mean if the current element use `+clearfix`, then the elements
that follow don't have to do a clear?  Actually I don't see any `clear` for the current element or the next one as a test using Firebug, so what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 3):

I'm running v0.10.5 and the source code partial in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.10.5/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_clearfix.scss` reads:

```
// This basic method is preferred for the usual case, when positioned
// content will not show outside the bounds of the container.
//
// Recommendations include using this in conjunction with a width.
// Credit: [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html)
@mixin clearfix {
  overflow: hidden;
  @include has-layout;
}
```

This is the SCSS syntax, but it's pretty directly analogous to the SASS syntax you reference. The `has-layout` mixin is included in the `_hacks.scss` partial in that same directory and appears to be specific to IE.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is, it does something like this:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This code generates an invisible block element after element.clearfix which clears the float. Probably there are also some additional hacks involved to make it work in IE < 8. You won't see anything in Firebug as it does not display generated content.